# Need to compare values in a Column with multiple conditions and sum values in other column using R

Tags: r

I have a data frame as follows

```
    name    dates   vol
    a             02/23/2017         1
    a             02/27/2017         2
    a             03/14/2018         10
    a             03/26/2018         8
    b             07/10/2017         5
    b             07/15/2018         15
    b             08/20/2018         25
```

I want to sum vol based on the same month and year
   i.e condition which checks if names and month+year are same then sum the 
        values from Vol

```
    expected output as:
     name  Total.Vol
     a          3         (1+2 sum of value which belong to same month+year
     a          18        10+8
     b          5
     b          35        (15+20)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(name, yrmon = format(as.Date(dates, "%m/%d/%Y"), "%Y-%m")) %>%
  summarise(Total.Vol = sum(vol))
```

Output:

```
  name  yrmon   Total.Vol
  <chr> <chr>       <int>
1 a     2017-02         3
2 a     2018-03        18
3 b     2017-07         5
4 b     2018-07        15
5 b     2018-08        25
```

Answer (score 0):

Form a column of Month and Year (using the library `lubridate` is the easiest) and then group by these new variables:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% mutate(Month = month(dates), Year = year(dates))

df %>% group_by(name, Month, Year) %>% count()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using function `as.yearmon` from package `zoo` to get a date of year/month and base R function `aggregate`.
But first convert the column to class `Date`.

```
library(zoo)

df1$dates <- as.Date(df1$dates, "%m/%d/%Y")

aggregate(vol ~ name + as.yearmon(dates), df1, sum)
#  name as.yearmon(dates) vol
#1    a          fev 2017   3
#2    b          jul 2017   5
#3    a          mar 2018  18
#4    b          jul 2018  15
#5    b          ago 2018  25
```

**Data.**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
   name    dates   vol
    a             02/23/2017         1
    a             02/27/2017         2
    a             03/14/2018         10
    a             03/26/2018         8
    b             07/10/2017         5
    b             07/15/2018         15
    b             08/20/2018         25                  
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well,didn't know we could work column to be a function of other columns.

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` based solution

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, dates := as.Date(dates, "%m/%d/%Y")]
df[, sum(vol), by = .(name, ym = format(dates, "%Y-%m"))]

   name      ym V1
1:    a 2017-02  3
2:    a 2018-03 18
3:    b 2017-07  5
4:    b 2018-07 15
5:    b 2018-08 25
```